# Differential ordinary equation. Can it be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the following ODE solvable?

$C'(t)=\lambda+\dfrac{1}{C(t)},\ \forall t\in I$-interval.

This one arises from a model of the blood alcohol concentration. See here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/zanran_storage/www.uwec.edu/ContentPages/18159357.pdf

Comment: **Hint :** You can rewrite the equation as $\frac{C(t)}{\lambda C(t)+1}C'(t)=1$. And then integrate on each side, using the change variable $x=C(t)$ on the left side. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: @HansLundmark : Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is separable $$\frac{dt}{dC}=\frac{C}{ \lambda C +1}=\frac{1}{ \lambda }\frac{\lambda C+1-1}{ \lambda C +1}=\frac{1}{ \lambda }\Big(1-\frac{1}{ \lambda C +1}\Big)$$ So, integrating both sides $$t+k=\frac{C}{\lambda }-\frac{\log (1+ \lambda C)}{\lambda ^2}$$ that is to say $$\lambda^2t+k= \lambda C- \log (1+ \lambda C)$$Extracting $C(t)$ is doable but requires Lambert function and, as a result, $$C(t)=-\frac 1 \lambda \Big(1+W\left(-e^{k-\lambda ^2 t}\right)\Big)$$ Admitting an initial condition $C(0)=C_0$, the constant $k$ would be given by $$k=\lambda C_0-\log (1+ \lambda C_0)$$

In fact, any equation which can write $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has solutions which express in terms of  Lambert function.